# Converting dateTime to Time and putting a where clause in it in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @Start DATE , @End DATE

SET @Start = '01/01/2019'
SET @End = '12/15/2019'

SELECT DISTINCT 
    Convert (Date,T.Reservation_date) [Date],
    Cast (T.Begin_Time as time) [Start_Time],
    DATENAME(dw,T.Reservation_date) [DateOfWeek]
FROM Table T    
WHERE Reservation_DATE BETWEEN @START AND @END
```

The output for casting the Begin_time is coming as example 10:03:17 0000000
I need to put use a where clause to filter the results where Begin_Time is >1700

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and desired results to clarify your question.

Comment: `WHERE Cast (T.Begin_Time as time) > '17:00'`

Answer (score 0):

You should put your date literals into an ISO format which will sort properly as dates:

```sql
DECLARE @Start DATE , @End DATE

SET @Start = '20190101'
SET @End = '20191215'

SELECT DISTINCT 
    CONVERT(Date, T.Reservation_date) [Date],
    CAST(T.Begin_Time AS time) [Start_Time],
    DATENAME(dw, T.Reservation_date) [DateOfWeek]
FROM Table T
WHERE Reservation_DATE BETWEEN @START AND @END;
```